# Who were the key thinkers in classical metaphysics, and what were the main problems they were trying to solve? What can I read on this topic?

Tags: metaphysics, history-of-philosophy

I'd like to read a history of classical metaphysics, but I am not even sure how to draw the boundaries of this topic to select a text for myself. I am specifically interested in system building, of a kind I am most familiar with in Whitehead and Peirce. It is their work that I ultimately seek to illuminate with a history of metaphysics of the kind that I am after, but I don't know my history of philosphy well enough to know which thinkers before the 20th century would be relevant.

As a starting point, here is Norris Clarke, in his book The One and the Many:

> Outside of the Thomistic and Scholastic tradi­tions, textbooks in
>   "Metaphysics" today usually mean something quite different from the
>   great classical tradition of systematic metaphysics in the style of
>   Aristotle, Aquinas, Duns Scotus, Spinoza, Leibniz, Hegel, Whitehead,
>   etc. The very notion of constructing a unified systematic
>   philosophical inquiry into being as a whole, distinct from other
>   philo­sophical disciplines, has been abandoned by most contemporary
>   phi­losophers (Whiteheadian Process philosophy is one of the few
>   excep­tions still flourishing).

Which other names would be appropriate for inclusion in a list like Clarke's? I'd add Peirce and Hartshorne in the twentieth century. Who else would be relevant from the full sweep of history?

To what extent were the classical metaphysicians responding to a common set of problems? They were not all concerned with the same problems, nor gave equal emphasis to the problems they did take as common, but presumably they shared some minimal set of concerns that allows them to be grouped together. Are there are any good books that survey a range of these thinkers in terms of common problems, or is it misleading to think of the topic this way?

Comment: There would be too many names "from the full sweep of history", I am afraid, he only has a single one from antiquity, and not one materialist overall. Could you narrow down the time period? [OOO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_ontology) is one of the most recent schools, from 21st century, and we have Russell, Heidegger, Sellars, Deleuze from the 20th, to name a few.

Comment: I realize I need to limit the number of candidates. I'll work on it. However, eliminating historical sweep would gut my question. I specifically want to get a feel for the history of metaphysical system building before Peirce and Whitehead in order to better understand the project that my exemplars have undertaken. I'm not gonna get that from recent history alone nor from any portion of history.

Comment: I was originally gonna limit the numbers by asking for the top two or three "tiers" of historical thinkers on the topic, but talk of tiers seemed to risk inviting too much opinion about historical importance.

Comment: See Kenny's New History Of Philosophy - Also Wndelband's History Of Philosophy "especial reference to the formation and development of its problems and conceptions"

Comment: Windelband , at archive.org

Comment: Hi Ray. Thanks for the Windelband. I'm grateful for older sources that are free but still respectable. I have very little money for books.

Answer (score 1):

Agree about Peirce. I'd add Bradley and Nagarjuna as unmissable. All three are on the same wavelength and shed light on each other. I would also add Lao Tsu for the clues he gives us, and Hermann Weyl for his analysis of time and space.

Metaphysicians all work on the same problem, which is axiomatising and building a fundamental theory. The project has been largely abandoned in modern academic philosophy because other than the theory offered by Nagarjuna and Bradley (and some would say Peirce) there is no way forward, while to go forward in their direction would require an investigation of mysticism.

If you're a fan of Peirce I'd recommend Andrew Ward and book called *'God and the World of Signs: Trinity, Evolution, and the Metaphysical Semiotics of C. S. Peirce*. Not easy to get hold of but a fabulous discussion.

It's odd nobody has mentioned Kant yet. While he didn't solve any problems I'd recommend reading the dictionary entries. This is the problem really, that most of the people you read will not understand metaphysics. If I had to pick two that have something truly helpful to say it'd be Nagarjuna and Bradley.

My suggestion for studying would be to proceed by topic, not by author. This allows a comparison of thoughts on a topic by topic basis and allows you to follow your own interests.

For the modern academic discipline I'd suggest the *Blackwell Guide to Metaphysics*. This is enough to put anyone off metaphysics forever, but it has the useful property of illustrating the dire state of metaphysical thinking in modern philosophy.

Another name might be Douglas Harding for his book *'The Hierarchies of Heaven and Earth'*.

My guess is that the only person I've mentioned who understands metaphysics is Nagarjuna. Of the four or five books I've read on his work I'd only recommend one, which is *The Sun of Wisdom* by Kenpho Tsultrim Gyamptso. A great deal of nonsense is written about Nagarjuna so some care is required, but this book is short and authoritative.

Good luck with your metaphysical investigation.

Comment: Garfield's translation of Nagarjuna's Fundamental Wisdom of the Middle Way is excellent. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://promienie.net/images/dharma/books/nagarjuna_mulamadhyamakakarika.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjyzOjuiuDoAhXZMMAKHbxKDK8QFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1_Vg2MhsJ45IVq1p_oX_G2

Comment: @IlyaGrushevskiy - It's a wonderful work of scholarship but I would not recommend it to anyone. He confuses and complicates all the issues and one could come away it with no proper grasp of Nagarjuna's philosophy. I believe it might be best to avoid this book.